# Not able to understand where white spaces are or indentation is missing in Python code : Line 6: SyntaxError: bad input (' ')

Tags: python

```
def name_to_number(name): 
    if name=='rock'
        number=0
    elif name=='Spock'
        number=1
    elif name=='paper'
        number=2
    elif name=='lizard'
        number=3
    elif name=='scissors'
        number=4
    else
        print'Not a valid input'
    return number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def name_to_number(name):
    if name=='rock':
        number=0
    elif name=='Spock':
        number=1
    elif name=='paper':
        number=2
    elif name=='lizard':
        number=3
    elif name=='scissors':
        number=4
    else:
        print 'Not a valid input'
        return number
```

With Python, indentation plays an important role. Read up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation

Comment: It worked with colon. Thank you! for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the colon at the end of each `if` and `elif` statement.

This is invalid:

```
if name == 'rock'
    number = 0
```

Python uses the colon as an indication that the next line should be an indented block. If you miss this colon then python thinks the next line should not be indented.

This is valid:

```
if name == 'rock':
    number = 0
```

As a general debugging principle if you get an error message and you cannot see anything wrong with the line number the error mentions check the previous line. An error in the previous line might not be discovered by the python interpreter until it reaches the next line and cannot interpret it.